# swiping with UIScrollView and moving up the view when using keyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview, uitextfield

I'm using [this](http://www.wannabegeek.com/?p=168) sample project and what I want to do is that when you put a `UITextField` on the view, when the `UITextField` in beneath the keyboard, the view moves up a little.

I've used the `TPKeyBoardAvoidingScrollView` class from [this](http://atastypixel.com/blog/a-drop-in-universal-solution-for-moving-text-fields-out-of-the-way-of-the-keyboard/) project. However when I click the `UITextField`, the view moves up and everything is fine but when I click on the background, instead of just restoring the normal screen size and dismissing the keyboard, it gets back to the first view instead of sticking at the view where we were at that moment.

Also you can scroll left and right when the keyboard is popped up, any idea how I can solve this? [Here](http://www.2shared.com/file/89j92UaT/PageViewController-master.html) is my project where I've added them both together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView.m there is a method(keyboardWillHide:) which gets called when keyboard is going to hide. In that method scrollview's content offset is set to CGPointZero, hence your scrollview is getting to first view controller.

```
- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification*)notification {
    _keyboardRect = CGRectZero;
    _keyboardVisible = NO;

    // Restore dimensions to prior size
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:[[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] intValue]];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:[[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] floatValue]];
    self.contentInset = _priorInset;
    //self.contentOffset = CGPointZero;//Replacing this with below line
    self.contentOffset = CGPointMake(self.contentOffset.x, 0);
    [self setScrollIndicatorInsets:self.contentInset];
    _priorInsetSaved = NO;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

To stop scrolling while editing textfield-

```
- (void)keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification*)notification {
    [self setScrollEnabled:NO];
    //existing code
}

- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification*)notification {
    [self setScrollEnabled:YES];
    //existing code with modification of content offset
}
```

Keep in mind this may affect on your other views where you use TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView's object.

Comment: Thanks, and how can I stop it that they can swipe right and left when the keyboard is popped up?